# Setup cdn in AWS and godaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, cdn, aws-api-gateway

Okay , i need help with right direction . I bought divyanayan.com domain in go daddy portal.

Second Step is, I created a certificate in AWS certificate manager , which gives me Cname and cValue . i used these cname and cvalue and added in the manage domain of godaddy domain i.e divyanayan.com . this validated my certificate .

After this was done i created a public api gateway endpoint and mapped to api gateway cdn .

```
https://vpyueoq2i9.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev
```

My requirement is i want to invoke this url from domain name divyanayan.com (which is configured using cname and cvalue of the certificate). what am i missing here  do i need to add the follwing mapping as well to godaddy i.e

```
divyanayan.com -> API Gateway domain name
```

Please let me know the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

With the setup that you currently have, I recommend using Cloudfront to serve as a proxy between your domain and your API Gateway endpoint. This would be beneficial in the long run if you want to map paths of the domain to other origins including other API gateway endpoints. You would also have more flexibility and control over how your traffic flows between your domain and the endpoint (eg. attaching lambda functions between API requests).

Here are two guides to help you get started:

1. Setting up API Gateway with cloudfront
   https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/
2. Setting up self-hosted/thirdparty-hosted domain with cloudfront
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html

Comment: Thanks Shayyan i was asked to change the approach a bit and use ec2 where my backend services would be hosted . i was able to create a domain name and reach ec2 by using route 53. www.divyanayan.com . now next step i need direction is how to make this url secure . i have ACM certificate and have added cname record as well to route 53. what other steps i need to take care to make it secure ?

Comment: Hello! I hope i'm not too late in response. 
To verify ACM cert, you need to go to ACM, copy CNAME name and CNAME value, then go to Route 53 to add these two entries as CNAME name and values and that's it. It'll take some time for it to verify. Give it a couple hours.
Also, if my orig answer helped you in anyway, could you mark it as selected? I'm new to this platform and need some reputation points haha.

Comment: i used ALB behind a route 53 and  target as ec2